# How to compare the difference between 2 months figures

Tags: excel

I'm trying to create a spreadsheet in Excel 2013 where I can compare the difference between this months and last months figures that will automatically update when i change the date.

I've 2 columns, date (A1) and figures (A2)

```
   A1      A2
jan-15    100
feb-15    150
mar-15    200
```

etc

I've got a vlookup setup to find the figures from the month that i select, but in the cell next to this result i'd like a formula to search for the previous months figures to what i've selected and subtract the figure. Ideally I'd like the result as a % as well.

Comment: Use the [DATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DATE-function-B91BEF00-4B5B-4EE0-B80E-06E68B1DFF29) to construct a date that is always the 15th of the month and the [EDATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/edate-function-1586b161-4361-4a6d-939b-9d96eae962a8) to add or subtract months from that date. [Percentages](http://www.mathsisfun.com/percentage.html) are usually a calculation of the two.

Comment: I do something similar to Jeeped but I use the last day of the month, then this formula will give you last months date which can be looked up: `=EOMONTH(A3,-1)` if you are using the start of the month then this: `=EOMONTH(A3,-2)+1`

Answer (score 0):

If A1 is in A1 and your dates are all the first of each month formatted as mmm-yy and your chosen month is say in D2, then please try:

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(D2,A:A,0))/INDEX(B:B,MATCH(D2,A:A,0)-1)-1
```

This finds the position your chosen month is within Column A, finds the corresponding value in ColumnB, divides that by the value immediately above and then subtracts 1. The cell with the formula may be formatted as `%`.